# How to dynamically create object page sections using controller in sap ui5?

Tags: sapui5

My requirement is to generate object page section containing different subsections and blocks inside it.

I have an api call which returns me the json something like this
**{sections:[{name:"section 1",subsections:{title:"Titleforsubsection 1",
"items":[{"abc":"test 1"},{"pqr":"test"}]}},
{name:"section 2", subsections:{title:"Titleforsubsection 2"},"items":[{"abc":"test 1"},{"pqr":"test"}]}]}.**

Now i need to create sections like label 1 containing subsection abc , label 2 containing subsection pqr and so on.

Is there any way to do it in xml? or I need to do it via controller? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you have the control over the API? Because it can be done, but your JSON is not optimal.

Comment: Yes I do, you are right the json is somewhat incorrect. Anyway, I figured out the way to do it after correcting the json by using something like this in my view 'sections="{myModel>/sections}" '. This iterates through the json and creates different sections. I have one more additional thing to do. In my blocks generated in subsections i need to create tables.  For example in above json i need to have  abc and pqr as 2 rows of table for blocks present in subsection 1, similarly for subsection 2. Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: Again, not with your current structure. Each subsection in your JSON probably needs a "table" or "tableItems" which contains an array with your items.

Comment: I corrected it, how do i create tables for it?